# Will phosphorous Ylide participate in carbene generation and insertion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

The following question was sent to me . The answer for this question was given to me as  option b

[image: questionabout carbene inscertion]

I attempted it as following , recognizing the first step as a ylide reaction with a carbonyl compound.
[image]

In order to get option B , I have to assume ylide generating a carbene and this may insert to double bond.

I have not come across phosphorous ylide as carbene generating reagent.

My question is as follows:

Will phosphorous Ylide participate in carbene generation and insertion in the presence of double bond ?

An answer in this regard would be quite help full.

Comment: I wasn't sure about phosphorous ylides, but cyclopropanation would be taken place with sulfur ylides. For example, the reaction of the Corey-Chaykovsky reagent with enones give corresponding cyclopropanes by undergoing a 1,4-addition that is followed by ring closure: _Tetrahedron Lett._ **2003**, *44(18)*, 3629-3630 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(03)00732-9).

Comment: For review on above reaction: https://doi.org/10.1021/cr960411r

Comment: I agree. This is not a carbene reaction. I think this takes place because of the high stability of the carbanion between the rings with elimination of Ph3P